# To compare the innertag values of two different Xml, and get the differences using XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

Xml1:-

```
<Demo name="Demo" MoneyFormat="" Type="" PricingCountry="IND" PricingCurrency="UD" PricingTerm="DP" PricingLang="99" >
    <Part ProductId="XFY-12" PartNumber="328806" Price="0.05" Description="ABCDE" />
    <Part ProductId="MER-14" PartNumber="328807" Price="0.85"  Description="FGHIJ" />
    <Part ProductId="MEM-24" PartNumber="328808" Price="72.87"  Description="KLMN" />
</Demo>
```

Xml2:-

```
<list version="1.0">
  <category name="XYZ"  psmax="0" idle="15" max="10">
    <imagename>sample.gif</imagename>  
    <chassis partnumber="328806">DellInspiron</chassis>
    <ComponentCollection>
      <component type="Processors" rel="OR" maxprocessors="2" minprocselect="1">
        <item type="Quad Core">
          <citem partnumber="328807" value="ABC"  idle="11" max="70" maxselect="2" />
          <citem partnumber="667421" value="DEF"  idle="11" max="70"  maxselect="2" />
        </item>
        <item type="Six Core">
          <citem partnumber="667376" value="GHE" idle="15" max="85"  maxselect="2" />
          <citem partnumber="667375" value="HIJ"   idle="14" max="92"  maxselect="2" />
          <citem partnumber="667424" value="KLM"  idle="14" max="64"  maxselect="2" />
          <citem partnumber="328808" value="NOP"  idle="16" max="106" maxselect="2" />
        </item>        
      </component>
</ComponentCollection>
</category>
</list>
```

In the above two different Xml files, I want to compare all the PartNumber of Ist Xml with IInd Xml and display the unmatched PartNumber.  I am a beginner in C# and XmlDocument, Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: There a number of ways to solve this problem.  One method that comes quickly to mind is to create a hash table on your "main" data and perform lookups against the hash table to find matches.  For records that do not match, push them into an "unmatched" array.  I'm sure there are more elegant approaches though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get all `PartNumbers` with `LINQ to XML` then use `Except` method

```
var list1 = XDocument.Load("firstpath")
            .Descendants()
            .SelectMany(x => x.Attributes())
            .Where(x => x.Name == "PartNumber")
            .Select(x => (string)x);
var list2 = XDocument.Load("secondpath")
            .Descendants()
            .SelectMany(x => x.Attributes())
            .Where(x => x.Name == "partnumber")
            .Select(x => (string)x);

var result = list1.Except(list2);
```

According to your file's content result will be empty because there is no `PartNumber` that exist in first file but not exist in second.If you want the opposite then use `list2.Except(list1)`